# If I have a $5\times 5$ symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ is there anyway to find what the eigenbasis looks like?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have a symmetric $5\times 5$ matrix $A$ that I know has $2$ eigenvalues, $1$ and $-1$. I want to find $A^{4}$. So by the Spectral theorem I have $A^{4} = QD^{4}Q^{T}$. Given that $D$ looks like a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$, is there anything we can deduce more about from $Q$?  I'm thinking that somehow $Q$ and $Q^{T}$ will simplify but not sure if we can narrow it down further.

Comment: Let $v$ be an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\pm1$. What is $A^4v$?

Comment: So it would be $v$ again.

Answer (score 1):

The most specific thing you can derive about $Q$ is that it can always be taken orthogonal, as you probably know (note that since we have repeated eigenvalues, not all bases are orthogonal).

Conversely, let $\{v_1,\ldots,v_5\}$ be any orthonormal basis. Then

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^5 \lambda_i v_iv_i^t$$

is a symmetric matrix and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_5\}$ forms a basis of eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, which can all be taken $\pm1$. In other words, all orthogonal bases are possible.

As per Hagen von Eitzen's remark, you don't need this to compute $A^4$.